# Docker GetServiceReferences: The given path's format is not supported

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, docker, docker-compose, azure-service-fabric

Trying to run locally a Web MVC application using `Docker`. Application compiles and runs fine when `Set as StartUp Project` outside of the `docker-compose` project but fails when `docker-compose` is `Set as StartUp Project` during the build when it comes to `Target DockerGetServiceReferences:` with

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(195,5): error : The given path's format is not supported.`

I have added the `docker-compose` through Visual Studio 2017 to an existing application as described here:

[How to containerize the .NET Framework web apps with Windows Containers and Docker](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopModernizing/wiki/02.-How-to-containerize-the-.NET-Framework-web-apps-with-Windows-Containers-and-Docker)

I appreciate this might be quite vague so if there are any more details I could provide please let me know.

**EDIT:**
Adding `docker-compose` to just default MVC template in a new project works fine so the problem seems to be with the legacy solution. Also noticed I can't navigate `docker-compose` project General Properties, I get the `URI formats are not supported` popup error

**EDIT:**
Adding a brand new MVC project from the template to the solution without any references to other projects also generates the error. Could this indicate that the problem might be somewhere on the solution level?

**EDIT:**
I have created a new Solution file and started to migrate all the projects. This way I am successfully able to compose docker image. Once I am finished migrating all of the project I will do a comparison on `.sln` files and try to see what is different.

Comment: Is difficult to give you help if you don't provide us with the file where you have these issues.

Comment: I get the issue when trying to add Docker through VS2017 to an existing MVC project. The Docker files do get added to the project and docker-compose project gets created but then when I run it I am getting the error. There is not a specific file I can see this relates to but I am happy to add any files that would help to narrow this down, just let me know which ones...

Comment: Have you been able to solve this?